# SQL Server : how to count each data in a column and set those data as a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question might be confusing but this is what I want to achieve:

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3
------+-------+------
3     | 5     | 11
```

What I've tried is this:

```
SELECT 
    [Items], COUNT([Number of Items]) AS Counts
FROM 
    [table] 
GROUP BY 
    [Items]
```

but this was the result:

```
Items | Counts
------+-------
Item1 | 3
Item2 | 5
Item3 | 11
```

How can I get those results above (the first one)?

Comment: Is your table has only 3 items, or the number of items is dynamic?

Comment: Its dynamic....